# _trackEvent on two accounts/subdomains, only one tracks properly

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to track blog.domain.com on it's separate Google Analytics account, as well as the the main account for www.domain.com.

GA snippet in `head` on blog.domain.com:

```
var request_uri = '/blog/article0001/';
_gaq.push(
    // blog.domain.com
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-99999990-1'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    // www.domain.com
    ['maintracker._setAccount', 'UA-99999991-1'],
    ['maintracker._setDomainName', '.domain.com'],
    ['maintracker._trackPageview', '/blog' + request_uri]
);
```

When a blog comment is posted using Ajax:

```
_gaq.push(
    // blog.domain.com
    ['_trackPageview', request_uri + 'commented/'],
    ['_trackEvent', 'Comment', 'Added comment',
    'Article title', ga_event_value],
    // www.domain.com
    ['maintracker._trackPageview', '/blog' + request_uri + 'commented/'],
    ['maintracker._trackEvent', 'Blog - Comment', 'Added comment',
    'Article title', ga_event_value]
);
```

All the four _trackPageView works fine. _trackEvent works fine for blog.domain.com, **but not for maintracker**.

GA reports "123 of your visits sent events", but no events actually shows in the statistics. I've waited 48 hours since the event fired.

[Google Analytics Debugger for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) reports `_gaq.push processing : "[maintracker._trackEvent,Blog - Comment,Added comment,Article title,2]"` and `Tracking beacon sent!`.

The tracking code on the main site www.domain.com looks like this:

```
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-99999991-1'],
    ['_setDomainName', '.domain.com'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
);
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the dash on the second Event? I've seen encoding issue with events with a dash that cause it to be dropped. Use "Blog > Comment" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing, it turns out that **multiple trackers can indeed be combined with cross-subdomain tracking**.

The problem was not the tracking code, but a filter with a typo on the www.domain.com account.

So I can confirm that the following actually works:

www.domain.com:

```
_gaq.push(
    // www.domain.com
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-99999991-1'],
    ['_setDomainName', '.domain.com'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
);
```

blog.domain.com:

```
var request_uri = '/blog/article0001/';
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-99999990-1'],
    ['_setDomainName', '.blog.domain.com'], // Not required, but gives overview
    ['_trackPageview'],
    // www.domain.com
    ['maintracker._setAccount', 'UA-99999991-1'],
    ['maintracker._setDomainName', '.domain.com'],
    ['maintracker._trackPageview', '/blog' + request_uri]
);
```

Analytics seems to grab all utm cookies, choose the correct cookie for each tracker (based on the hash at the start of all cookie values), and then write correctly to the cookie on the proper domain. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Take out:

```
['maintracker._setDomainName', '.domain.com'],
```

It is overwriting the tracking cookie for `domain.com`

Multiple trackers are set up without `_setDomainName`

```
_gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1'],
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2'],
  ['b._trackPageview']
);
```

[One Push, Multiple Commands](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands)

It doesn't look possible to add cross-domain tracking and multiple trackers at the same time. See:

[Pitfalls of Tracking to Multiple Accounts in Google Analytics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2009/02/26/pitfalls-tracking-multiple-accounts-ga/)

and

[How do you setup cross domain tracking when using multiple analytics trackers?](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-tracking-and-implementation-issues/op71Aa0WKmU)

Comment: Thanks jk. Are you sure this is correct? [Google Analytics Help: Tracking Across a Domain and Its Subdomains](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#domainSubDomains) says "even if you manage both a domain and a sub-domain, you must make modifications to the tracking code in order to share visitor data across both domains".

Comment: @elaxsj Either do one or the other. You are dumping the same page into **two** different profiles. Cross-domain tracking dumps into **one** profile.

Comment: So what I want to achive is not possible? It seems to work fine for the pageviews, but not for the events.

Comment: @elaxsj It works for pageviews because it sends that before you change the cookie. The event tracks after the cookie is changed.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. The cross-domain tracking is most important, so then I will use this account as the name-less tracker and `setDomainName` to `.domain.com`, and track the event only this. But can I add a simple extra tracker for the blog, just using `_setAccount` and `_trackPageview` on this? Due to user permission issues, I would like to track page views on the blog on a completely different account, instead of making different profiles on the main account with a Hostname filter.

Comment: @elaxsj I updated my answer with a couple links that will explain that cross-domain tracking and multiple trackers should not be mixed.

Comment: Sorry I'm picky. Your answer is accepted so you are free to answer or not ;) In [a followup to the "pitfalls" article](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2009/03/06/cookies-tracking-multiple-accounts-ga/), the author writes: "(..) each tracker use[s] completely different cookies.  At this point you no longer have the problems listed above.  You can track some pages to both accounts, and other pages to just one account without any conflict. You can use different User Defined Segments on each. And you can use cross domain tracking for one set of Tracking Code but not the other."

Comment: I can see that GA places a cookie both for blog.domain.com and domain.com, so based on the info in the followup article, one should think it should work. The _blog.domain.com cookie_ should be used for the first account (single-domain tracking), and the _domain.com cookie_ should be used for the second account (cross-domain tracking). But I realise that it does not work, so I guess you are perfecly correct.